# Error playing bagfile ~4GB on 32bit system

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have no problem with the info comand, but when I am trying to play a bagfile but i am gettint an error.

```
[FATAL] [1425331406.887155495]: Error opening file: 2015-02-13-10-04-56.bag
```

Bagfile Info:

```
duration: 1:40s (100s)
size: 3.8 GB
83651 msg
```

My friend has no problem in play this bagfile. I have test the example with the turtle and I can reproduce it well. May be the problem because the baffile is very large and my computer is not very new?

I am using Xubuntu 32bit and my friend is using Ubunt 64bit.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204082/error-playing-bagfile-%7E4gb-on-32bit-system/) by [carlogarro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21756/carlogarro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-02**:
Can you post the bagfile or get a backtrace?

**Comment by [carlogarro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21756/carlogarro/) on 2015-03-03**:
The bagfile is arround 4gb. So it is difficult to post it. How can I get a backtrace?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-03**:
32 vs 64 bit issue perhaps? You haven't stated which OS you are using (and which version), nor the ROS release this is happening on.

**Comment by [carlogarro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21756/carlogarro/) on 2015-03-03**:
I am using a 32bits Xubuntu version. So what do you think I should do?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-03**:
I don't know, but 4GB is close to typical 32bit filesize limits. Please update your original question with OS info for your PC and that of your friend.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-03**:
I've taken the liberty of updating the question title to better reflect what the issue is.

**Comment by [carlogarro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21756/carlogarro/) on 2015-03-03**:
Ok, there is no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but [ros_comm/issues/464](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/464) ("rosbag throws rosbag::IOException at 2GB mark") could be related.

You did not update your question with the version of ROS you are using, but the last comment on [ros_comm/pull/554](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/554) ("support large bagfiles (>2GB) on 32-bit systems in rosbag_storage") seems to suggest this hasn't made it into Hydro yet, so you could be running into issue 464.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [carlogarro](https://answers.ros.org/users/21756/carlogarro/) on 2015-03-03**:
In the end, my teacher uploaded the same bagfile with less size and it has worked perfectly, so i suposed it has been the problem.

Thank you so much for your help!